# Prove that if X is contractible to $x_0$ ∈ X, then a loop γ at $x_0$ is homotopic to the constant loop.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My textbook defines a space X to be contractible to $x_0 ∈ X$ with $x_0$ held fixed if there is a map $F:X×[0,1]→X$ such that

- ${F(x,0)=x_0}$, $x∈X$
- ${F(x,1)=x}$, $x∈X$
- ${F(x_0,t)=x_0}$, $0≤t≤1$

Two paths $γ_0$ and $γ_1$ from $a$ to $b$ are said to be homotopic with endpoints fixed if there's a map $H:[0,1]×[0,1]→X$ such that

- ${H(s,0)=γ_0(s)}$, $0≤s≤1$
- ${H(s,1)=γ_1(s)}$, $0≤s≤1$
- ${H(0,t)=a}$, $0≤t≤1$
- ${H(1,t)=b}$, $0≤t≤1$

I was given the hint that I need to make some composite function to show that any loop at $x_0$ is homotopic to the constant loop at $x_0$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Being "contractible to $x_0 \in X$" is not really a standardized concept. In the sense of your textbook it means that $X$ is what I would denote as *pointed contractible* to $x_0 \in X$. See my answer to [Is Armstrong saying that the comb space is not contractible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3574480) for definitions.

Anyway, taking the homotopy $F$ from your question, the map $H(s,t) = F(\gamma(s),t)$ has the desired properties:

1. $H(s,0) = F(\gamma(s),1) = \gamma(s)$
2. $H(s,1) = F(\gamma(s),0) = x_0$
3. $H(0,t) = F(\gamma(0),t) = F(x_0,t) = x_0$
4. $H(1,t) = F(\gamma(1),t) = F(x_0,t) = x_0$